# HTML not displaying images

Tags: html, browser, rich-text-editor

So I am just starting out coding HTML and I am using the textedit app on Mac which has worked fine for me for a long time but just recently I went to turn off the autocorrect feature in the preferences and it seemed to mess everything up, now I can't display images (even if the link is correct and they are in the right folder) or even hyperlinks. Regular text like headings and paragraphs still show up though. Does anyone have any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: without seeing any code at all, it would be impossible to guess.

Comment: post something more meaningful that just plain text in a question.